# Maximize my sales (response) for the given set of constraints

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, optimization, prediction, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to optimize my business. Please give me some suggestions.

**Problem Statement:**

I need to maximize my sales for the given total budget (total budget can vary from minimum to maximum bound based on fixed intervals)

*for example:* let's say my minimum budget is 100K and maximum budget is 200K and the objective is to maximize the sales for 100K,110K,120K...200K budgets.

**Granular details:**

Total Budget comes from different granular variables (let's say X1,X2..Xn)

*My constraints are,*

```
1)X1+X2+X3....+Xn=Total Budget

2)X1 >= 10K and X1<=20K

  X2 >= 13K and X2 <= 50K

  ......

  Xn >= 20K and Xn <= 30K
```

**Note**:
I have already built a non linear model using my past data, and I would like to use the same set of coefficients for the optimization.

Will be really helpful if you can give me some suggestions on this. Also please let me know if you have any difficulties in understanding above requirement.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by *granular* variables? Are they discrete variables, or continuous ones? 2. For a given vector $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$, how do you compute sales (the objective you want to maximize)? Do you have an explicit expression  $sales=f(X_1,\dots, X_n)$? Is $f$ a linear function, or is it nonlinear  (maybe it's the nonlinear model you are referring to)? If nonlinear, can you show us is expression or at least give an idea about it? Is it a spline model? Gaussian process? Neural Network? Is it cheap to evaluate and smooth? Do you have access to gradients?

Comment: Hi DeltalV, Thanks for the reply. When I say granular variables, they are nothing but model inputs at atomic level (can't be broken further). For this discussion, just assume them as model inputs (X1,X2...Xn). Yes Sales is a function of  (X1,…,Xn)(X1,…,Xn). The equation is (Y=Bo*X1^CF1*X2^CF2...Xn^CFn). CFs are estimated from convex optimization.

Comment: Good: you should include the expression for $f$ to your question. Probably this can be solved with some canned optimization algorithm -  I'll try to write an answer in the next days. **NOTE**: coefficients of power-law terms are hard to estimate, and multiplicative models like yours are rarely used in my field. If you're sure that your model has good predictive performance, because of domain knowledge references and/or metrics such as cross-validation, fine. Otherwise, I'd ask another question about the best model for your application, before betting money on the results of this optimization.

Comment: In the expression $Y=Bo*X_1^{CF_1}*X_2^{CF_2}\dots X_n^{CF_n}$, are all the  $CF_i$ positive? Also, all the granular variables positive, right? According to your constraints, they should be.

Comment: Thanks DeltalV for the effort in helping me. Yes in my domain this multiplicative model works well. I have a good cross-validation results too. To answer your second question, Yes ! All the CFs are positive in nature. Yes I am forcing my CFs to be positive (Ax-b>=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the question & comments, you have the following optimization problem (I use the symbol $\alpha_i$ to denote the $CF_i$) :

$$\max_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n}{f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i}}$$

subject to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = c; \ 0 < a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i \ \forall i \in 1,\dots, n$$

with $\alpha_i \geq 0 \ \forall i \in 1,\dots, n$. This is a particular instance of what is called a [Geometric Programming (GP)](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/gp_tutorial.pdf) problem. GP can be transformed to a convex optimization problem by just taking the log of your objective function: since $\log{x}$ is a monotone function, and since all your $x_i$ are strictly positive, then maximizing your objective is equivalent to maximizing the objective

$$\max_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n}{\log{f(x_1,\dots,x_n)}=\sum_{i=1}^n {\alpha_i}\log{x_i}}$$

Now, since also all $\alpha_i$ are strictly positive, the new, equivalent optimization problem:

$$\max_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n}{g(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n {\alpha_i}\log{x_i}}$$

subject to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = c; \ 0 < a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i \ \forall i \in 1,\dots, n$$

is a Convex Optimization problem. You are familiar with convex optimization, so I trust you shouldn't have any issues solving this optimization problem, now. Anyway, to make the answer more useful for other users, I note that in MATLAB [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) by Stephen Boyd and al. is available, which is an excellent, easy to use tool for convex optimization. If $n$ is small enough (I think in the order of tenths), the free version should be able to nail it. If one doesn't have a MATLAB license, [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/), the Python version of CVX, should be able to do the job. I've never used it, I only know that's it a bit less developed than CVX, for now. By the way, [CVX is able to deal with Geometric Programming problems natively](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/gp.html): you don't need to use the log-transform, you can just tell CVX that you have a GP problem and it will make the transform, get results and transform them back to your original formulation. Very convenient!

Unfortunately, I don't know about good convex optimization tools for R. If someone knows about them, I'd be happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already programmed an existing nonlinear model, your code should have an an existing error function.  One method that is simple to program is to return a very large error when the parameters are outside of the constraints, as if hitting a brick wall.  If you use this technique, you must verify that the fitting results are not at or very near to any of the constraints as the results may not be valid.  Variations on this nonlinear fitting technique exist such as slowly increasing the error as a constraint is approached, but this "brick wall" is easy to program and often effective.